# Stop songs shuffling in iOS Music app

Tags: iphone, itunes

In the Apple's Music app on my iPhone, when I press the play button, the music titles begin shuffling through all of the songs and will not stop shuffling.

How do I stop songs from shuffling?

Answer (score 2):

On the Now Playing screen in the Music app, scroll downwards and tap on the shuffle button to turn it off.

The shuffle button is concealed in the UI and it's placement isn't obvious.

[image] [image]

**Image Source**: http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/16/shuffle-music-ios-10/